Can't setup JSONb type. Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode'
I want to save a data from JSON string in Postgres where I have a column with JSONb type. But I getting exceptions. I'll be glad so much for helping me.
I have an Entity for game's maps:
package com.dragon.dungeon.entities;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "maps")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MapEntity {

    @Id
    @UuidGenerator
    private UUID id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity ownerId;
    
    @Column(name = "data", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
    private JsonNode data;

}

I use Spring Boot 3.2.4, so as I have read I need to use own data type for that. So I created it:
package com.dragon.dungeon.entities.character;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Objects;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class JsonNodeUserType implements UserType {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public int getSqlType() {
        return Types.OTHER;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> returnedClass() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) {
        return Objects.equals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) {
        return Objects.hashCode(x);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, int position, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws SQLException {
        String json = rs.getString(position);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readTree(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new HibernateException("Failed to convert JSON string to JsonNode", e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws SQLException {
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
                st.setObject(index, json, Types.OTHER);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new SQLException("Failed to convert object to JSON string", e);
            }
        } else {
            st.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
            return objectMapper.readTree(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Failed to deep copy JsonNode", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) {
        Object copy = deepCopy(value);
        if (copy instanceof Serializable) {
            return (Serializable) copy;
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Value is not serializable: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) {
        return deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) {
        return deepCopy(original);
    }

}

And edited an application.properties like this:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.types.registration.jsonb.type=com.dragon.dungeon.entities.character.JsonNodeUserType
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.types.registration.jsonb.package=com.dragon.dungeon.entities.character

But when I want to start my application, I got an error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode'

What should I do? What's wrong with my code?
